# NameError: name 'Area' is not defined

Tags: python, django, excel

I made area data model in models.py.

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area')

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='region')
            prefecture = models.ForeignKey(Prefecture)

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
            PRICE_RANGE = (
                ('a', 'under500'),
                ('b', '500-1000'),
                ('c', 'upper1000'),
            )
    price_range = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRICE_RANGE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

When I run migration command,`NameError: name 'Area' is not defined area = models.ForeignKey(Area)` error happens.However,I defined Area,so I really cannot understand why this error happens.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the`Area` class before `User` class. Things should be fine.

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area', null=True)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='region')
            prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture')

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
            PRICE_RANGE = (
                ('a', 'under500'),
                ('b', '500-1000'),
                ('c', 'upper1000'),
            )
    price_range = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRICE_RANGE)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')
```

Comment: Or quote Area, like this: `area = models.ForeignKey('Area')`

Comment: @Varad thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but when I run ./manage.py makemigrations,I got an error You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'area' to transaction without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py.

Comment: @Varad So,I added default to the code area = models.ForeignKey('Area', default=""),when I run ./manage.py migrate after ./manage.py makemigrations, return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_user.area_id .What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @user8504021 You should change it in the `class Area` to have default for `name` . flush all the existing stuffs from db and migrate.

Comment: @Varad I cannot understand ur comments.If i write ur comments in codes,how should I write?

Comment: @user8504021 I am unable to look at this error now. I will check and get back to you later today.